# det(AB)=det(A)det(B) using the permutations formula

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

[image]

Can somebody help me understand this theorem? I don't understand the part when it creates another sum with $r_1,r_2,...,r_n$

Comment: Try doing it by hand on $2\times 2$ matrices to see what happens.

Comment: I think it's because if $C=AB$, then $C_{ij}=A_{ik}B_{kj}$.

Comment: I understand that, but the next row is where I got stuck

Comment: To be honest, I can't clearly understand this type of notations. But can't just he "remove" the brackets and move the sum sign to the front?

Comment: He has a product of $n$ sums, and he's expressing it as a sum of products.  That is, you choose one term from each sum and multiply them together, then you add up all such products.  For example, $$\sum_i{a_i}\sum_j{b_j}=\sum_{i,j}{a_ib_j}$$  That is $$(a+b+c)(d+e+f)=ad+ae+af+bd+be+bf+cd+ce+cf$$

Comment: Ahh yes, thank you. You made it much more easy